# Return value of key from associative array when key is known

Tags: php, wpml

So I am trying to echo the value of a key if the key is present in the array. I've go this code at the moment:

```
<?php
    $lingos = array(
        "en"=>"en_US", 
        "en-gb"=>"en_GB", 
        "nl"=>"nl_NL", 
        "de"=>"de",
        "da"=>"da",
        "es"=>"es",
        "ca"=>"es_MX",
        "fr"=>"fr",
        "it"=>"it",
        "pt-pt"=>"pt_PT",
        "no"=>"no",
        "sv"=>"sv",
        "fi"=>"fi",
        "et"=>"en_GB",
        "is"=>"en_GB",
        "cs"=>"cs",
        "pl"=>"pl",
        "lv"=>"en_GB",
        "lt"=>"lt",
        "hu"=>"hu",
        "ro"=>"ro",
        "sr"=>"en_GB",
        "hr"=>"en_GB",
        "bg"=>"bg",
        "el"=>"el",
        "uk"=>"en_GB",
        "ru"=>"ru",
        "tr"=>"tr",
        "ar"=>"ar",
        "zh-hans"=>"zh_CN",
        "zh-hant"=>"zh_TW",
        "ja"=>"ja",
        "ko"=>"ko",
        "id"=>"in",
        "ms"=>"ms",
        "th"=>"th",
        "vi"=>"vi",
        "pt-br"=>"pt_PT"
    );

    // foreach($lingos as $lingo => $x_lingo) {
    //     echo "Key=" . $lingo . ", Value=" . $x_lingo;
    //     echo "<br>";
    // }


    $wmpl_langcode = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
    echo $wmpl_langcode;
    if (array_key_exists($wmpl_langcode, $lingos)) {
        echo $lingos[1];
    } else {
        echo "not found";
    }
?>
```

Thing is, $lingos[1] is not returning anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By 1 I mean the second index. I know the key is being found, so how to return the value of the found key?

Comment: You want to echo the value of the index that is found so `echo $lingos[$wmpl_langcode];`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to echo the langcode but the value of its key. So when I echo $wmpl_langcode I get 'nl' but I acutally want to echo 'nl_NL'

Comment: That's exactly what it does.

Comment: Your key is `$wmpl_langcode`, the value is `$lingos[$wmpl_langcode]`.

Comment: Excuse me, but you're absolutely right. $lingos[$wmpl_langcode] <-- seems to solve my problem. Thank you all, lifesavers!

Comment: When I learned JS, I remembered that in order to return the second index in an array, you should use [1]. But I guess it works differently in PHP. Live and learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `$wmpl_langcode` is something like `en` as you are checking for it with `array_key_exists` so use that as the index:

```
$wmpl_langcode = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
echo $wmpl_langcode;
if (array_key_exists($wmpl_langcode, $lingos)) {
    echo $lingos[$wmpl_langcode];
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Or simpler:

```
echo isset($lingos[$wmpl_langcode]) ? $lingos[$wmpl_langcode] : "not found";

//PHP 7+
echo $lingos[$wmpl_langcode] ?? "not found";
```